# NullPointerExecption in bundle after AsyncTask

Tags: android, bundle, android-asynctask, android-intent

I'm having a problem with this Activity.

```
    package com.ilocal.diary;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ViewDiary extends Activity {

    private String userid = "1";
    private String response;
    private String url;
    private Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.empty_layout);

        this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...", true, false);

        bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            userid = bundle.getString("USERID");
        }
        url ="http://www.ilocaltest.x10.mx/android/fetchdiary.php";
        postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));

        new PHPQuery().execute(url, postParameters);
    }

    private class PHPQuery extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String > {
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, postParameters);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("HTTP error - " + e.toString());
            }
            System.out.println(response);
            return response;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println(result);
            if (!(result == null)) {
                bundle.putString("RESPONSE", result);
                Intent i = new Intent(ViewDiary.this, DisplayDiary.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
                ViewDiary.this.finish();
            }
            else
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working until i try the bundle the result from the AsyncTask when I get a nullpointerexecption in the line

```
bundle.putString("RESPONSE", result);
```

I know that the result has been passed to the onPostExecute method so where is the exception coming from and how can fix it.

Martin

Comment: With `if (!(result == null)) {` That should be the same as `if (result != null) {` Just thought you should know that, and either `bundle` or `result` has to be null, I'm guessing it's result since it's only getting there if result is null.

Comment: Can you put a debug log in here and see if it runs?

  bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null) {

        userid = bundle.getString("USERID");

        Log.d("PHP", "Found extras");

    }

Comment: @Christopher Added that and the extra are found. I knew already that there was no real bundle so a created a new activity inorder to send a bundle and removed creating a new bundle and it works. It must have been the bundle that was null. But why should that make a difference. In the previous activity where bundle is created it will be empty until a string is put into it which would be the same int this activity.

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate bundle, but then you assign to it `this.getIntent().getExtras();` which is `null` if the intent was fired with no bundle, which is probably the case. check for null before putting into the bundle, and if null, instantiate it.

Even better, check if null after `getExtras()` and instantiate if so:

```
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle == null)
    bundle = new Bundle();
else {//...
```

Comment: Thanks MByD but the problem was putting the extra and not getting them

Comment: I was trying to develop it as a standalone activity and then put it into the main app once it was working, so i thought i could instantiate the bundle in order to test the activity and then remove it once it was placed in the main app where it would recieve a bundle from the intent. In future I will just a dummy activity to launch the intent from.